# Does LIMITing a SQL query after ORDERing improve execution time?

Tags: sql, performance

Would the second query execute significantly faster than the first one?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY timestamp;

SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY timestamp 
LIMIT 100;
```

If no, what would be the fastest way of getting the `n` latest out of `N` records where `n << N`?

Comment: Significantly, maybe or maybe not, depending on your definition of `"significant"`. It all depends on the number of rows in the table. What percentage of all rows is 100 rows? Is it 1%, 10%, 50%? If 100 rows is 0.1% of the contents of the entire table, then most probably yes, it's going to be significantly (noticeably) faster. Anyway, as with any performance-oriented task the correct answer is: ***it depends***. And there are a lot of other factors that can influence this.

Comment: That is the fastest way to get your result.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thanks for your answer. Then I guess my follow up question would be: why? If `n = 100` and `N = 1 000 000` the first query would be executed with an `O(nlog(n))` time. In the second case `LIMIT` doesn't help, all the rows need to be sorted anyway. Unless there are some other optimisation steps in place? For instance I can imagine that if `n << N` it might be faster to call `max` `n` times than sort everything

Answer (score 0):

If You need to improve speed of this, add index on `timestamp`.